# Always past tense when telling someone's history?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, past-perfect

> Tom's father had instilled him an interest in **how things work.**

Should it be how things **work** or how things **worked**? It all happened in the past but "how things work" seems to be a general thing that Tom still is interested in today.

Did the fact that Tom is dead or alive make any difference in tense? Are there any difference in **work/worked** here? Or is one of them grammatically incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "should" involved here. It's perfectly okay to use EITHER Present Tense ***work*** OR Simple Past ***worked*** in the cited context.

This is completely unaffected by whether the *primary* verb *(**instilled**)* stands alone as a Simple Past verb form, or is preceded by ***had*** to form a Past Perfect construction. Effectively, it's the same kind of optional "backshifting" that we often use in contexts like *He said his name **was** Smith* (as opposed to ***...is*** Smith).

---

Note that "how things work" is really a "timeless" reference (unless context specifically points out that *things have changed since then*, which doesn't seem to apply to OP's question). So whereas with my ***Smith*** example we couldn't use Present Tense *(...**is** Smith)* if he'd since changed his name or died, there's no real sense in which that kind of restriction could apply to OP's example.